# Ansible local_action directive

Tags: ansible

I'm quite new to Ansible and have a simple question for my understanding of `local_action` directive.

Would that mean that the command is fully executed locally? Let's say you have something like this:

```
local_action: command which nginx
register: check_nginx
failed_when: no
changed_when: no
```

Then you have another block looking for nginx's existence with something like that:

```
- fail: msg="nginx unavailable"
  when: check_nginx.rc == 1
```

Does that mean that playbook will fail in case nginx is not installed locally or will it fail if is not installed remotely ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, `local_action` is an alternative way of doing `delegate_to: localhost`.

These actions will be executed on local machine (Ansible control host), but still being in context of remote host in terms of variables. So you can something like this:

```
local_action: command ping -c 1 {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

which will ping every host in your play, but ping will be initiated from Ansible control host.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer, just what I was looking about and I now know why it was setup the way it was on the playbook I'm using (externally written not me)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to be safe though, does that mean you can still ping ip addresses and host in your local area network when you use local_action/ -c local in ansible right, but it is simply initiated from the host you are running from?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to provide multiple parameters to the local action it will look something like this

```
local_action: 
  module: command
  _raw_params: "which nginx"
register: check_nginx
failed_when: no
changed_when: no
```

Comment: Thank you, I was searching for "_raw_params" part that is missing on Ansible Docs